# Visual Studio 2012 ASP.NET Empty Web Application LESS support

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less, web-essentials

Ok, so I'm using Visual Studio 2012, with web essentials 2012, and I just created a new ASP.NET Empty Web Application. I added a LESS file to my styles folder and referenced it accordingly. Now, as it seems, this new ASP.NET Empty Web Application doesn't support LESS compilation right out of the box.

What I wanted to know is if that assumption is correct, and, if so, which is the best option to bring in support for LESS compilation on the server? Less.js? dotLess.js?

I'm still kinda confused when it comes to LESS compilation on the server, because I don't want to compile it on the client, like just adding the less.js script to the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Mindscape have a vs plugin which allows support of less files. It's called web workbench
http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench
They offer a free version. I've used it in a few projects to good effect.

Comment: Visual Studio itself supports LESS files; you don't need that.  He's asking for runtime support

Comment: @SLaks yes, that's it. I did a little more research and, as it seems, you need at least to include the dotLess.core library to have LESS support on the server, and add the handlers in the web.config file. Correct me if I'm wrong.